# Python Heroku Cronjob need 2nd dyno with APScheduler?

Tags: python, heroku, cron

I have an app on heroku and use the 7 Dollar payed dyno and the 9 Dollar posgresql DB.

Now I need a cronjob. It should query all my users and send an email to some of them. I believe this task can take a few minutes. I plan to run it at night once a day.

I plan to use the [APScheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-python). I already found here some informations but I am still not sure whether I need to buy one more dyno or my dyno will handle it?

Thats my current procfile:

```
web: gunicorn main:app --timeout 120
```

I always thought 1 line in the procfile means use of one more dyno, so here I would use a clock process:

```
clock: python clock.py
```

Also how are cronjobs tested? I plan to create a lot of example users and set the cronjob to execute the next day, so I can see who got an email and who not?

---

Is a second dyno needed here?

Will this affect the costs?

How are cronjobs tested whether they execute as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my needs the [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) was good enough, it is free and very simple to use.

> it executes scheduled jobs via one-off dynos that will count towards your monthly usage.

It simply executes a `.py` file by itself. It does it by executing `python my_task.py`. You could do the same manually via `bash`.

I use it to send out a few hundred emails and it works great. Keep in mind that tasks, which need longer than 5~ min. to run should use a custom clock process, which is an additional dyno.

Also:

> Scheduler job execution is expected but not guaranteed. Scheduler is known to occasionally (but rarely) miss the execution of scheduled jobs.

You can test you jobs by simply typing in the command `python my_task.py` by yourself. You can also change the frequency of the cron job to execute every 10 min. Here is the example:

[image]